# Display an object as a morris chart

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I try to display my data as a morris bar chart. I write a function in nodejs that return my data as :

```
[{date: 32, energiep1: 3, energiep2: 0},{date: 32, energiep1: 4, energiep2: 0}]
```

my code is:

```
 var calcule=function(callback)

       {

     mesure_energie = new calcul_energie(function(mesures)
      {
      var l=mesures.length;
      for(i=0; i<l; i++)
      {
   var mesure_Valeur = JSON.parse(mesures[i]);

      data=data+"{date: "+mesure_Valeur.date
        +", energiep1: "+mesure_Valeur.energiep1
        +", energiep2: "+mesure_Valeur.energiep2+"},";

      }
    data=data.substr(0,data.length-1);
    data=data+"]";
    datas=data.toString();

    callback(datas);         

         });
```

after that i tried to display a morris chart as this

```
  <head>
 <title>MongoDB Web App</title>
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-
 min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- Use EJS to print out our data-->

 <div id="bar-example"></div>


 <script>

 Morris.Bar({
 element: 'bar-example',
data:datas,
xkey: 'date',
ykeys: ['energiep1', 'energiep2'],
labels: ['Series A', 'Series B'],
pointSize: 2,
hideHover: 'auto',
resize: true

});
</script>
</body>
```

I don't understand what's wrong. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, the problem is with these three things. Lets check it again.

- CDN paths (Replace with these) as mentioned on [morrisjs](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/) website as well.

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
  ```
- Also make sure that the variable `datas` is defined. It shouldn't be emppty.
- I also noticed that you didnt include morris.css as well.

  I tried your code by doing above these things and its working. Check it out jsfiddle below.

```js
var datas = [{date: 32, energiep1: 3, energiep2: 0},{date: 32, energiep1: 4, energiep2: 0}];
new Morris.Bar({
 element: 'bar-example',
data:datas,
xkey: 'date',
ykeys: ['energiep1', 'energiep2'],
labels: ['Series A', 'Series B'],
pointSize: 2,
hideHover: 'auto',
resize: true

});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>

<div id="bar-example" style="height: 250px;"></div>
```

Comment: thanks. Yes it's working now. Do you know if we can display the format date with morris.js??

Comment: @SirineAbed If it is working then please accept my answer by ticking the correct icon. Thanks

Comment: Let me see the format date thing and will get back to you.

Comment: ok thanks. This is the format date new Date("2016-05-18T16:00:00Z"). I tried but it doesnt work.